# Learn geometry with Euclid's Elements

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'am an high school student who want learn more about Euclidean Geometry.
I started to read Euclid's Elements (a few propositions).Is it good way to learn geometry or is better to read modern text.

Answer (score 4):

Reading Euclid's *Elements* is not really necessary and you'd probably learn faster from a more recent text on the subject, but there is something to be gained from the intellectual challenge that comes with reading it, especially since he did not use symbolic algebra and other forms of mathematical notation that are commonplace today. If you intend to read it as a challenge, then by all means go ahead: you will be able to see the mathematical process of reasoning by one of the greatest minds of antiquity. Otherwise, I would say that there are probably more efficient texts for learning geometry if that is your ultimate goal.